# xsi:nil in xslt - how to use it

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to set xsi:nil to element but got this:

```
Attribute 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance, nil' must not appear on element 'xsl:element', because the {nillable} property of 'xsl:element' is false.




<xsl:element name="elem" namespace="namespace" xsi:nil="true">
    <xsl:text></xsl:text>
</xsl:element>
```

Comment: Do you want to create a result element `<elem xmlns="namespace" xsi:nil="true"/>`? Then you can just write that literally in XSLT. If you need to compute the element name or namespace then please show  a sample doing that. If you then use `<xsl:attribute name="xsi:nil" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">true</xsl:attribute>` inside of the `xsl:element` you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: You can't just randomly put attributes on `xsl:element`. If you want to add attributes to the element you are creating, use `<xsl:attribute>`. This is true for anything, not just `xsi:nil`.

Answer (score 0):

From §11.1.2 of the XSLT 3.0 specification (equally applicable to earlier versions):

> The xml:base, xml:lang, xml:space, and xml:id attributes have two
>   effects in XSLT. They behave as standard XSLT attributes, which means
>   for example that if they appear on a literal result element, they will
>   be copied to the result tree in the same way as any other attribute.
>   In addition, they have their standard meaning as defined in the core
>   XML specifications. Thus, an xml:base attribute in the stylesheet
>   affects the base URI of the element on which it appears, and an
>   xml:space attribute affects the interpretation of whitespace text
>   nodes within that element. One consequence of this is that it is
>   inadvisable to write these attributes as attribute value templates:
>   although an XSLT processor will understand this notation, the XML
>   parser will not. See also 11.1.4 Namespace Aliasing which describes
>   how to use xsl:namespace-alias with these attributes.
>
> The same is true of the schema-defined attributes xsi:type, xsi:nil,
>   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation, and xsi:schemaLocation. If the
>   stylesheet is processed by a schema processor, these attributes will
>   be recognized and interpreted by the schema processor, but in addition
>   the XSLT processor treats them like any other attribute on a literal
>   result element: that is, their effective value (after expanding
>   attribute value templates) is copied to the result tree in the same
>   way as any other attribute. If the result tree is validated, the
>   copied attributes will again be recognized and interpreted by the
>   schema processor.

In practice what this means is that it's best to avoid including these special attributes literally in a stylesheet. If you want to generate them in the result tree, use `xsl:attribute` to achieve it. You could also use `xsl:namespace-alias` to use a different namespace URI aliased to the "special" URI.